# intranet form builder

Tags: windows, web-apps, html, forms

I'm looking for a GUI form builder that fulfills the following requirements:

1. Enables to build forms without access to the internet
2. Enables to publish the forms in the intranet
3. Enables to save the submitted forms somehow
4. Works on windows

Can anyone please suggest a software that matches these requirements?